# Debug Zuul route to underlying microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I use Spring boot. I am working on a defect. When we call account service through Zuul endpoint it gives 400 bad request. Account service as standalone works as expected. Only issue seems to be when call routed by / coming through Zuul endpoint. Now I am debugging this.

I started account service on localhost port 8032 with my debug points added and verified it works when I call through my local host in POSTMAN. So this works as usual. Then I went to Zuul and provided in application properties `zuul.routes.account.url=http://localhost:8032`. I started Zuul on different port on my local host. So when I call Zuul through my localhost in POSTMAN, I expect the call to go to account service which is running on port 8032 and expect to hit the debug point I set. But it does not happen at all. I get 400 bad request.

When I changed to `zuul.routes.account.url=http://localhost:8050` in Zuul application properties and call Zuul through postman , it gives me error saying there is no application running on port `8050` means the value I set for `zuul.routes.account.url` is being set up as expected ( There is nothing deployed on port 8050, I have account service on port 8032). I can't seem to figure out why I don't hit debug point in account service deployed on 8032 port when I call Zuul localhost through POSTMAN.

Comment: Are you passing any headers?

Comment: Yes I am passing headers Authorization. It seems call is going through.

Comment: you need to tell zuul to let authorization header thru since it removes it by default. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#cookies-and-sensitive-headers

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for reply. I am under impression if headers are being removed by default, then the account service may error out . I do not get 401 unauthorized , I do get 400 bad request. Even if prod same thing happens. My issue is not that I get 400 bad request. It does not hit the endpoint I set, that's I am stuck at. I am reading article you sent

Comment: @spencergibb I kept this empty ```zuul.routes.cx.sensitiveHeaders=``` and I still get same results, not hitting the debug point.

Comment: can you provide you configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause, it was with http header size. I need to increase it to 10,000 from 5,000 and worked just fine. Sharing so others can find it useful.